# Excel copy data from another sheet based on criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have 2 Excel sheets and I want to copy data from sheet2 to sheet1
when the data in sheet1 is the same as in Sheet2

I tried Vlookup and INDEX-MATCH and i couldn't get them to work

Sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

I want to copy the Nr from Sheet2"B" to Nr in Sheet1"C" When the ID in sheet1 is the same as in sheet2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about Vlookup?

Comment: i tried to use Vlookup and INDEX-MATCH they didnt work and i'm not that good with Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data in Sheet2 is:

[image]

And in Sheet2 I got:

[image]

The formula I've used in Sheet1 in Cell C2 (and then drag down) is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5;2;FALSE)
```

Comment: im getting #NAME? error and the IDs from 1-5 and Nr are only an example i have alot more

Comment: If you have more ID's to match, you just need to make the range bigger. And about NAME error, adapt the formulas to your needs. Make sure it fits the names of your sheet2 and also make sure you type the name of the function correctly

Comment: still the same error  and I even tried it with same tabels as in your answer and still the same NAME error

Comment: Can you post an image how how you are doing it in your original question?

Comment: it works now thanks. VLOOKUP didnt work I used SVERWEIS

Comment: Of course. VLOOKUP is the name of the function in english. You just need to change the name of the function to your language settings :)